# Vertical line when plotting sf object around 180 degree antimeridian

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapping, gis, r-sf

A lot of goofy things seem to happen when you have to map things in the middle of the Pacific Ocean and your objects span the antimeridian at 180° longitude. In my case, I'm plotting a shapefile (which can be [found here](http://geo.pacioos.hawaii.edu/geoserver/PACIOOS/hi_noaa_nwhi_papahanaumokuakea_line/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=hi_noaa_nwhi_papahanaumokuakea_line&outputFormat=SHAPE-ZIP)) using `sf` and `ggplot` and there's a solid vertical line at 180°.

Is there a way to get rid of this thing or is it somehow baked into the shapefile? Currently I'm just loading the shapefile, hitting it with an `st_shift_longitude`, and plotting it. I tried various iterations of `st_combine` and `st_union` hoping either one would smash together what appear to be two separate polygons, but to no avail. Here's the basic plot. How can I get rid of this vertical line?

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(tidyverse)
pmnm <- st_read("data/gis/hi_noaa_nwhi_papahanaumokuakea.shp",quiet = TRUE) 

ggplot(pmnm %>% st_shift_longitude()) + 
  geom_sf()
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a helpful comment. I did in fact do that search (you're right, there are a bunch of questions that pertain to "antimeridian" and [r]), but none of the questions seemed to address this issue. If I missed something that you didn't, I'd very much appreciate a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a feature of the specific shapefile and how it was being plotted.